# UpdateModel + NHibernateException "identifier of an instance of xxx was altered from x to y"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I'm using ASP.NET MVC with NHibernate

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country  { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a page to edit a User,
there is a dropdownlist to choose the country

I'm using UpdateModel() to update the User.
It works fine for User.Name.
It updates User.Country.Id but not User.Country.Name
(because the page only send Country.Id). So I'm using this : User.Country = countryDao.Get(User.Country.Id)
but when i save the user i have a NHibernateException : {"identifier of an instance of Country was altered from 1 to 2"}

What could i do ?

Comment: If you  want to save changes on referenced entity set Cascade to Update. Set Country Id prop to private set; and look if it compiles.

Answer (score 1):

Error :

```
        var db = new BaseServices<Supplier>();
        Supplier item = db.Get(model.SupplierID);

        **TryUpdateModel(item);
        item.Locality = new BaseServices<Locality>().Get(model.Locality.LocalityID);**           
        db.Update(item);
        db.SaveChange();
```

Slution :

```
        var db = new BaseServices<Supplier>();
        Supplier item = db.Get(model.SupplierID);

        item.Locality = new BaseServices<Locality>().Get(model.Locality.LocalityID);
        TryUpdateModel(item);
        db.Update(item);
        db.SaveChange();
```